# How to get value from GetElementById?

Tags: c#, .net, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

nxuybcbkbcbggkcwcbregrwyywbrgewbyrewyreyrwebyrwrwe
test

Comment: `HtmlElement` is not valid in the context of `CefSharp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync();
```

Sends javascript to be executed and expects nothing in return, so trying to assign 'nothing' (ie void) to an HtmlElement variable is a no go.

If you are looking to send the page a bit of javascript, and use what is sent back, you need to use `EvaluateScriptAsync()`

This will return a `Task<JavascriptResponse>` which will still not work if you are trying to assign it to `Size`. Here is the bad news: `JavascriptResponse` can only be basic data types (int, bool, string, etc.). As per their documentation:

> Only trivial values can be returned (like int, bool, string etc) - not
>   a complex (user-defined) type which you have defined yourself. This is
>   because there is no (easy) way to expose a random Javascript object to
>   the .NET world, at least not today. However, one possible technique is
>   to turn the Javascript object you wish to return to your .NET code
>   into a JSON string with the Javascript JSON.toStringify() method and
>   return that string to your .NET code. Then you can decode that string
>   into a .NET object with something like JSON.net. See this MSDN link
>   for more information.
>   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx)

For more info see: 
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions

Comment: There is limited support for arrays/dictionaries of primitive types, if you return `[0,1]` you'd get a list of objects which can be parsed into integers.